# PySpark : How to cast string datatype for all columns

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

My main goal is to cast all columns of any df to string so, that comparison would be easy.

I have tried below multiple ways already suggested . but couldn’t succeed :

```
target_df = target_df.select([col(c).cast("string") for c in target_df.columns])
```

this gave error :

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "Can't extract value from SDV#155: need struct type but got string;"
```

Next one I have tried is :

```
target_df = target_df.select([col(c).cast(StringType()).alias(c) for c in columns_list])
```

error :

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "Can't extract value from SDV#27: need struct type but got string;"
```

Next method is :

```
        for column in target_df.columns:
             target_df = target_df.withColumn(column, target_df[column].cast('string'))
```

error :

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "Can't extract value from SDV#27: need struct type but got string;"
```

Few lines code that exists before cast :

```
        columns_list = source_df.columns.copy()
        target_df = target_df.toDF(*columns_list)
```

schema of sample df on which im trying :

```
root
 |-- A: string (nullable = true)
 |-- S: string (nullable = true)
 |-- D: string (nullable = true)
 |-- F: string (nullable = true)
 |-- G: double (nullable = true)
 |-- H: double (nullable = true)
 |-- J: string (nullable = true)
 |-- K: string (nullable = true)
 |-- L: string (nullable = true)
 |-- M: string (nullable = true)
 |-- N: string (nullable = true)
 |-- B: string (nullable = true)
 |-- V: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C: string (nullable = true)
 |-- X: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Y: string (nullable = true)
 |-- U: double (nullable = true)
 |-- I: string (nullable = true)
 |-- R: string (nullable = true)
 |-- T: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Q: string (nullable = true)
 |-- E: double (nullable = true)
 |-- W: string (nullable = true)
 |-- AS: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DSC: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DCV: string (nullable = true)
 |-- WV: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SDV: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SDV.1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- WDV: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FWFV: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ERBVSER: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: what does `target_df.dtypes` show?

Comment: I think there is at least one column of type struct type in the dataframe, so it obviously can't be casted to string.

Comment: @jxc added schema in the question

Comment: @XavierCanton   added schema in the question

Comment: @pault added the two lines of code which before the casting

Comment: @sitaramchikkala, the error is from the `dot` in the field name `SDV.1`. adjust your code to something like: target_df = target_df.withColumn(column, target_df['\`{}\`'.format(column)].cast('string'))

Comment: when the column name contains `dot`, you will need to use back ticks to surround the fieldname when referring it through `df[column]` or `col(c)`

Comment: @jxc that worked, you can submit answer ill accept it. thanks a lot.

just another question will this handle all special characters in column names?

Comment: @sitaramchikkala, yes, backtick will handle all special characters that allowed in the column names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested, the error was from the dot `.` in the column named `SDV.1` which has to be enclosed with back-ticks when selecting the column:

```
for column in target_df.columns:
    target_df = target_df.withColumn(column, target_df['`{}`'.format(column)].cast('string'))
```

or

```
target_df = target_df.select([col('`{}`'.format(c)).cast(StringType()).alias(c) for c in columns_list])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your approach

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,25),(1,20),(1,20),(2,26)],['id','age'])
>>> df.show()
+---+---+
| id|age|
+---+---+
|  1| 25|
|  1| 20|
|  1| 20|
|  2| 26|
+---+---+

>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)

>>> df.select([col(i).cast('string') for i in df.columns]).printSchema()
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: string (nullable = true)

>>> df.select([col(i).cast('string') for i in df.columns]).show()
+---+---+
| id|age|
+---+---+
|  1| 25|
|  1| 20|
|  1| 20|
|  2| 26|
+---+---+
```